# replace word in list of strings using python

Tags: python

I have a script that I am trying to optimize for work and I basically need to replace the "username" in the script with the username of the person. I eventually want to do this over and over for a list of people but I am having trouble with what seems like a very basic part.

```
f = open("Exiting.txt","r") #opens file with name of "exiting.txt"

line1 = (f.readline())
line2 = (f.readline())
line3 = (f.readline())
line4 = (f.readline())
line5 = (f.readline())
line6 = (f.readline())
line7 = (f.readline())
ext = input("Enter a name to exit: ")

lst = [line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7]
for line in lst:
    line = line.replace("username",ext)
print(line1)



line1 = line1.replace("username",ext)
print(line1)
```

When I run this, I get the first print out exactly the same as it was before (and all the other lines are the same as well) and the second line is more like what I want

I want the for loop to loop over and over the lines replacing the word `username` with the actual username.

> Enter a name to exit: millingtonc
>
> mkdir "\qnapnas01\archive\Data\Users\username"
>
> mkdir "\qnapnas01\archive\Data\Users\millingtonc"

Comment: You're replacing `line` in the loop, but not changing `lst`. You'll need to create a new list to append your replaced lines to, and use that list.

Comment: `for line in lst: newlines.append(line.replace("username",ext))`.

Comment: You should post as answer, Evert

Comment: you should read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to make your code efficient with file reading/writing. Use [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to manage file opening/closing automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are changing the value of variable `l` instead of the `line1` in `lst` or variable `l1` itself. Following codes should help you do the trick:

```
lst = [line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7]
for i in range(len(lst)):
   lst[i] = lst[i].replace("username",ext)
```

I am not sure the final results but the basic idea is you can change the value in list and actually replace the string that you ask for.

Comment: I mean you are changing the value of variable `line` and `line1`. Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

Changing the string in the for-loop won't change the `line1` variable. Also, you should probably find a better way to read from the file in the first place which could help you to avoid this problem. I suggested one way below but there are numerous other ways you can accomplish essentially the same thing.

```
ext = input("Enter a name to exit: ")

with open("Exiting.txt", "r") as f:
    lst = [f.readline() for _ in range(7)]

lst = [line.replace("username", ext) for line in lst]
print(lst)
```

Comment: `lst = (f.readline() for _ in range(7))` don't do this. Use `f.readlines()` instead. To strip `\n` character, use `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Nah, no need to read the whole file into memory if the OP only wants the first seven lines. I just accidentally made it a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're overwriting a temporary variable (line) which only exists in the scope of the loop, so you're not seeing any changes to your other variables (line1, line2, etc.). So you need to store the replaced values in a separate list outside the loop, like so:

```
replacedLines = []
for line in lst:
    replacedLines.append(line.replace("username",ext))
```

Or, using a list comprehension:

```
replacedList = [line.replace("username",ext) for line in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it thanks to Evert and cuongnv

```
f = open("Exiting.txt","r") #opens the exitng.txt which has 7 lines

line1 = (f.readline())
line2 = (f.readline())
line3 = (f.readline())
line4 = (f.readline())
line5 = (f.readline())
line6 = (f.readline())
line7 = (f.readline())
f.close()
ext = input("Enter a name to exit: ")

lst = [line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7]
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    i = i.replace("username",ext)
    lst2.append(i)
for d in lst2:
    print(d)
```